# Tag coordinates and ginput - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I wish to tag/mark coordinates on an axes in App designer using this simple code but without success. Any idea how to do it directly on the axes (app.ImageAxes)?

Code:

```
function ButtonPushed(app, event)
        imshow('cameraman.tif','Parent',app.ImageAxes); 
        app.ImageAxes.HandleVisibility = 'on';
        [x,y,button] = ginput(5)
        app.ImageAxes.HandleVisibility = 'off';
    end
```